# Docker compose runtime arguments

Tags: docker-compose

I want to pass the runtime arguments from `docker run .... --arg=x` inside docker-compose.yml

```
version: "2.8"
services:
  atlantis:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
       gitlab-hostname: "X"
       gitlab-webhook-secret: "X"
       gitlab-user: "X"
       gitlab-token: "X"
       repo-allowlist: "X"
    ports:
      - "4141:8081"
    image: "runatlantis/atlantis"
```

It seems that it doesn't work: `atlantis_1  | Error: --gh-user/--gh-token or --gh-app-id/--gh-app-key-file or --gitlab-user/--gitlab-token or --bitbucket-user/--bitbucket-token or --azuredevops-user/--azuredevops-token must be set`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Use `command` instead of `environment`:

```yaml
version: "3"

services:
  atlantis:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "4141:8081"
    image: "runatlantis/atlantis-custom"
    command: 
      - server
      - --gitlab-hostname="X"
      - --gitlab-webhook-secret="X"
      - --gitlab-user="X"
      - --gitlab-token="X"
      - --repo-allowlist="X"
```